# Vector image as background

Tags: import, image, svg, movie-clip-editor

I am making a video using chroma key effect. The foreground would be a movie file and the background would be a vector image created with "pdflatex" (initially the image is a pdf), so it is a pdf file.

In the compositing context of blender, I add a node "image" so that I could import my pdf background. However I can't import such file.

A pdf file contains both raster and vector elements so I tried to raster the file with inkscape as mentionned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape?newreg=2c602f52f5934868ad0803c06f71a215) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66773/how-to-import-pdf-file-into-blender)  but it doesn't work and I find this method a bit messy (I have a lot of pdf files).

I try to change the compilation of my latex document to a format compatible with blender.... on-going

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compositor only imports bitmapped images like OpenEXR tiff png jpeg etc. Perhaps you could open the pdf in a pdf app then export it or try screen grabbing it. To use svg files you can try importing them as an object in the 3d view then film that with the 3D camera. This can be added to the compositor as a "Scene" node.

Comment: I rasterized my image. In fact, it's a bit stupid to deal with pdf file with blender since the render will not take into account the vector properties of this file ....